DDD Identifier, autoincrement ID and UUID
I'm developing web application project in Typescript while learning and applying DDD (domain driven design) at the same time.
In our database we use autoincrement ID's for the primary keys. But this approach no ID will be ready until an entity is persisted.
In DDD every entity that is created, no matter where, should have its identifier defined from start, so what happens when an entity is created before it is saved to the database? (for example it is created in the frontend). Then, no ID will be available.
In DDD as well its said that every value that is not a entity should be a Value Object, hence the identifier should be a value object as well.
With those premises, I thought of a UniqueEntityID value object that will do the following:

The UniqueEntityID holds 2 attributes, uuid and autoincrementId.
When the ID is created, if no value is passed to the contructor, it will use a randomly generated uuid, but if a value is given, it will stored in the autoincrement id attribute.
To get the real value of the ID, there's a value getter, that will provide the autoincrementId if it exists or the uuid if not.

This way, whenever the entity is retrieved from the database using the repository it will come with the autoincrementId as the value, but to the newly created entities, it will use the UUID.
At the moment of saving an entity, if the ID is not persisted it is removed from its attributes, so the new entity is created in the database and a new ID is generated.
Please tell me if this approach is correct, or if it is an anti pattern, or if I'm missing something.
This is the code used for the UniqueEntityID.
class UniqueEntityID {
  private readonly uuid: string
  private readonly autoincrementId: number

  /**
   * Creates an identifier using UUID implementation,
   * used when the entity is not yet persisted.
   */
  constructor()
  /**
   * Creates an identifier using the autoincrement ID
   * from the database.
   * @param id - The ID given from a database autoincrement.
   */
  constructor(id: number)
  constructor(id?: number) {
    if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
      this.uuid = v4()
    } else {
      this.autoincrementId = id
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check if the ID is an autoincremented ID generated by
   * the database
   */
  get isPersisted() {
    return typeof this.autoincrementId !== 'undefined'
  }

  /**
   * The value of the ID.
   */
  get value() {
    return this.autoincrementId ?? this.uuid
  }
}

Best regards,
Jorge


Please tell me if this approach is correct, or if it is an anti pattern, or if I'm missing something.

I think the need for this fancy pattern is unclear.
The key question being this: is an autoincrement column in a database suitable for use as an identifier?  Or is instead just metadata of the database?
For example, in a distributed system, one of the problems we may need to worry about is duplication of input messages - what happens if we receive a second copy of an "insert new entity in the database" message that we have already processed?
Assuming that we don't want multiple copies of the same information in the data model, there needs to be some way of identifying the fact that this row already exists.  Checking for an identifier is the most straight forward mechanism to do that... but if you are relying on the database to generate the identifier during the insert process, that check isn't available.
See also: Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging.
In short, you might be better off using a UUID everywhere (not necessarily a randomly assigned UUID, but a name-based UUID might allow you to generate identifiers deterministically with acceptable collision risk).

Thank you for your answer.
Well, there's no distributed system requiring handling of message in that context. So actually I do indeed want to use the auto increment ID of the database as identifier. But as a ID is needed in the application for any entity, even when it hasn't been persisted yet, that's the reason for this pattern, to be able for them to have an ID before it's persisted.
I understand what you're saying here, and problably best option would be to use just UUID to simplify things but I find it too little user frienendly like for using it as a the URI component in the URL.
